# mongoDB, node JS and shortest path function, any option available?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shortest-path

At work we have being maintaining a location application based in Node JS + Mongo DB (Mongoose). The geolocation functionalities we needed were very simple and available in MongoDB already ($near, $geoWithin and $geoIntersect). Our main problem just came with a requirements, were we need to make usage of a "shortest path" function to check best routes between some of the locations we got stored.

Looking and searching in internet, seems that mongo doesn't have a shortest path function and some articles suggest to deal with a second database to perform this task (neo4j or postgis).

The question is, exist a affordable way to achieve the shortest path functionality with mongo and node only? or if deal with a second database what could be the best combination?.

UPDATE

Recently I found the $graphLookup feature in mongo DB 3.4, in the Mongo db Europe 16 meet up talks about how can be useful to track shortest path. Is this currently a proper feature to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native operation in mongodb that performs shortest path calculation.

If you would like to avoid the cost of implementing, maintaining and synchronizing a separate graph data store and if the graph's size is not prohibitively large then you could load the nodes, edges and weights (or distances) into memory and perform shortest path calculation in javascript.

To avoid implementing the shortest path algorithm yourself you can use a library such as [node-dijkstra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dijkstra)

According to node-dijstra documentation you need to initialize the graph providing weights for every edge and then invoke the `path` function.

```
const Graph = require('node-dijkstra')

const route = new Graph()

route.addNode('A', { B:1 })
route.addNode('B', { A:1, C:2, D: 4 })
route.addNode('C', { B:2, D:1 })
route.addNode('D', { C:1, B:4 })

route.path('A', 'D') // => [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
```

Comment: thanks cjungel, actually this is one of the possible solutions, the main problem is that in many cases the amount of nodes could be extensively large to just load it in memory based that thousands of users potentially will use this feature.

Comment: @dakairus in that case I think your only option is to introduce a new data store to your architecture. Depending on your real-time requirements and the volume of your data you could implement a periodic import of your graph into neo4j or another grapth store. You could then use neo4j for real time shortest path calculations. If you always need the latest data to be considered in your calculations then I think you should modify your application to use neo4j for storage and querying of all graph related     operations.